# Qr scanner not showing result

Tags: android, ios, flutter, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am trying to implement a QR scanner in my project using barcode_scan dependency. When I run the code in the different project it works fine but when I use the exact same code in my project it shows no scan result.
I am working with Provider architecture in my project but I am making this page independent of Provider.

```
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'dart:io' show Platform;

    import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

   // void main() {
  //   runApp(AttendeeQrscanner());
   // }

   class AttendeeQrscanner extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   AttendeeQrscannerState createState() => AttendeeQrscannerState();
   }

  class AttendeeQrscannerState extends State<AttendeeQrscanner> {
  ScanResult scanResult;



 var _aspectTolerance = 0.00;
 var _selectedCamera = -1;
 var _useAutoFocus = true;
 var _autoEnableFlash = false;

 static final _possibleFormats = BarcodeFormat.values.toList()
..removeWhere((e) => e == BarcodeFormat.unknown);

 List<BarcodeFormat> selectedFormats = [..._possibleFormats];


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 var contentList = <Widget>[
  if (scanResult != null)
    Card(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Result Type"),
            subtitle: Text(scanResult.type?.toString() ?? ""),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Raw Content"),
            subtitle: Text(scanResult.rawContent ?? ""),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Format"),
            subtitle: Text(scanResult.format?.toString() ?? ""),
          ),
          ListTile(
            title: Text("Format note"),
            subtitle: Text(scanResult.formatNote ?? ""),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),



   ];
   return MaterialApp(
   debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
   home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Barcode Scanner Example'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
          tooltip: "Scan",
          onPressed: scan,
        )
      ],
    ),
    body: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: contentList,
    ),
   ),
  );
 }

Future scan() async {
try {
  var options = ScanOptions(

    restrictFormat: selectedFormats,
    useCamera: _selectedCamera,
    autoEnableFlash: _autoEnableFlash,
    android: AndroidOptions(
      aspectTolerance: _aspectTolerance,
      useAutoFocus: _useAutoFocus,
    ),
  );

  var result = await BarcodeScanner.scan(options: options);
 print("scan resulllt $result");
  setState(() => scanResult = result);
 } on PlatformException catch (e) {
  var result = ScanResult(
    type: ResultType.Error,
    format: BarcodeFormat.unknown,
  );

  if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.cameraAccessDenied) {
    setState(() {
      result.rawContent = 'The user did not grant the camera permission!';
    });
   } else {
    result.rawContent = 'Unknown error: $e';
   }
  setState(() {
    scanResult = result;
  });
  }
 }
}
```

What my debug console shows

D/mali_winsys( 6082): EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/SurfaceView( 6082): surfaceChanged (1080,2214) 1 #8 io.flutter.view.FlutterView{32a2498 VFE...... ........ 0,0-1080,2214}
D/ViewRootImpl@49ab5fMainActivity: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1 1
D/InputMethodManager( 6082): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@6f74f31[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 6082): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
D/InputMethodManager( 6082): prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@6f74f31[MainActivity]
D/InputMethodManager( 6082): getNavigationBarColor() -855310
V/InputMethodManager( 6082): Starting input: tba=com.event.eventusAiV3 ic=null mNaviBarColor -855310 mIsGetNaviBarColorSuccess true , NavVisible : true , NavTrans : false
D/InputMethodManager( 6082): startInputInner - Id : 0
I/InputMethodManager( 6082): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport( 6082): Input channel constructed: fd=106
D/InputTransport( 6082): Input channel destroyed: fd=111
D/SurfaceView( 6082): onWindowVisibilityChanged(8) false me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview{d627f45 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1116,1984} of ViewRootImpl@ab30553[BarcodeScannerActivity]
D/SurfaceView( 6082): show() Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.event.eventusAiV3/de.mintware.barcode_scan.BarcodeScannerActivity@d627f45@0[6082])/@0xa15669a me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview{d627f45 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1116,1984}
D/SurfaceView( 6082): surfaceDestroyed callback.size 0 #2 me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview{d627f45 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1116,1984}
D/SurfaceView( 6082): destroy() Surface(name=SurfaceView - com.event.eventusAiV3/de.mintware.barcode_scan.BarcodeScannerActivity@d627f45@0[6082])/@0xa15669a me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview{d627f45 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1116,1984}
W/libEGL  ( 6082): EGLNativeWindowType 0x79354bd010 disconnect failed
D/OpenGLRenderer( 6082): eglDestroySurface = 0x7963f22180, 0x79354bd000
D/ViewRootImpl@ab30553BarcodeScannerActivity: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,2340] new=[0,0][1080,2340] result=0x5 surface={false 0} changed=true
D/ViewRootImpl@ab30553BarcodeScannerActivity: stopped(true) old=false
D/SurfaceView( 6082): windowStopped(true) false me.dm7.barcodescanner.core.CameraPreview{d627f45 V.E...... ........ 0,0-1116,1984} of ViewRootImpl@ab30553[BarcodeScannerActivity]
D/ViewRootImpl@ab30553BarcodeScannerActivity: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputTransport( 6082): Input channel destroyed: fd=104

Comment: Worth reviewing [ask].

Comment: thank you. I am not fond of asking questions here.

Comment: @DonMag sir can you go through my question again.

Answer (score 1):

I just went with fast_qr_reader_view plugin instead of barcode_scan. I am pulling my own leash at this point but I thought my answer could help someon else.